# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos en una tabla HMTL usando PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, aplicación-web

Estoy intentando mostrar el registro que hay en la base de datos, pero me da el siguiente error. He metido un registro como prueba para saber el momento en que ya funcione pero no, ni siquiera lo registra en el contador que tengo

[image: Solo tengo un registro hecho y no lo cuenta tampoco]

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Estoy usando MySQL como base de datos. Esta es la vista para mostrar los datos o registros que se están llevando a cabo

Les anexo la vista para el codigo de la tabla HTML con PHP

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">nombre del empleado</th>
                    <th scope="col">primer apellido</th>
                    <th scope="col">segundo apellido</th>
                    <th scope="col">fecha de nacimiento</th>
                    <th scope="col">rfc</th>
                    <th scope="col">curp</th>
                    <th scope="col">foto</th>
                    <th scope="col">departamento</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                $nReg = 0; 
                foreach ($data as $key => $empleado):  
                    $nReg++; ?>
                 <tr>
                        <td> <?php echo $empleado['id_empleado'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $empleado["primer_apellido"] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $empleado["segundo_apellido"] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $empleado["fecha_nacimiento"] ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $empleado["rfc"] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $empleado["curp"] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $empleado["foto"] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $empleado["id_departamento"] ?></td>
                        
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                                <a href="empleado.php?action=task&id=<?php echo $empleado["id_empleado"] ?>"
                                    type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Ingresar</a>
                                <a href="empleado.php?action=edit&id=<?php echo $empleado["id_empleado"] ?>"
                                    type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Modificar</a>
                                <a href="empleado.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $empleado["id_empleado"] ?>"
                                    type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach ?>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Se encontraron
                        <?php echo $nReg ?> registros.
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Les dejo el controlador también, son las unicas 2 cosas que tengo. La conexión a la base de datos esta en otro archivo pero no hay problema con eso.

```
<?php
require_once("sistema.php");
class Empleado extends Sistema
{
    public function get($id = null)
    {
        $this->db();
        if (is_null($id)) {
            $sql = "select * from empleado";
            $st = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $st->execute();
            $data = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {
            $sql = "select * from empleado where id_empleado = :id";
            $st = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $st->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $st->execute();
            $data = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function new($data)
    {
        $this->db();
        $sql = "insert into empleado (empleado) values (:empleado)";
        $st = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindParam(":empleado", $data['empleado'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();
        $rc = $st->rowCount();
        return $rc;
    }
    public function edit($id, $data)
    {
        $this->db();
        $sql = "update empleado set empleado = :empleado where id_empleado = :id";
        $st = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->bindParam(":empleado", $data['empleado'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();
        $rc = $st->rowCount();
        return $rc;
    }
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db();
        $sql = "delete from empleado where id_empleado = :id";
        $st = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();
        $rc = $st->rowCount();
        return $rc;
    }
}
$empleado = new Empleado;
```

Comment: Los mensajes de error son bastante claros. ¿Dónde has definido a la variable `$data`? Si vas a tomar los datos usando la clase, debes instanciar la clase y llamar al método que te devuelve los datos.

Comment: Saludos. Mientras te llega una solución; mi sugerencia (no estoy familiarizado con la sentencia `foreach(...): ...  endforeach`); te sugiero en vez de `foreach(...):` usar `foreach(...) {` y en lugar de `endforeach` colocar `}` _(el cierre de `foreach`) y verifica con ese cambio. Y para `Se encontraron <?php echo $nReg ?> registros` prueba con `Se encontraron <?php echo count($data) ?> registros`.

Comment: Es decir, antes del `foreach`, debes instanciar la clase y llamar al método que te devolvería los datos, algo así: `$unEmpleado = new Empleado(); $data=$unEmpleado->get(); foreach ($data as $key => $empleado):`

Comment: @RobertoLeOr OP está usando la [sintaxis alternativa](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). Pero ese no es el problema aquí. Bueno, yo no uso nunca esa sintaxis, aunque en algunos frameworks sí les gusta usarlas.

Answer (score 1):

Los mensajes de error son bastante claros. ¿Dónde has definido a la variable `$data`? Si vas a tomar los datos usando la clase, debes instanciar la clase y llamar al método que te devuelve los datos y a continuación leerlos.

Aparte de eso, dado que `fetchAll()` te devuelve un array, puedes usar `count()` para saber cuántas filas hay.

Por último, no deberías pasar a construir la tabla sin verificar primero si habrá datos para meter en esa tabla. Y, no conozco mucho la sintaxis alternativa de PHP que usas en tu bucle, pero no creo que sea correcto omitir los `;` al final de cada línea dentro de los bloques php.

Así debería funcionar salvo que haya otros errores:

```
<?php
 /*
    OJO: Aquí debes hacer include o require del archivo
    donde tienes la clase Empleado
 */
 $unEmpleado = new Empleado();
 $data = $unEmpleado->get(); #Le puedes pasar un id también
 if ($data) {
   foreach ($data as $key => $empleado): ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">nombre del empleado</th>
                                <th scope="col">primer apellido</th>
                                <th scope="col">segundo apellido</th>
                                <th scope="col">fecha de nacimiento</th>
                                <th scope="col">rfc</th>
                                <th scope="col">curp</th>
                                <th scope="col">foto</th>
                                <th scope="col">departamento</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $empleado["id_empleado"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $empleado["primer_apellido"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $empleado["segundo_apellido"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $empleado["fecha_nacimiento"]; ?> </td>
                                <td><?php echo $empleado["rfc"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $empleado["curp"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $empleado["foto"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $empleado["id_departamento"]; ?></td>

                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                                    <a href="empleado.php?action=task&id=<?php echo $empleado["id_empleado"]; ?>"
                                    type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Ingresar</a>
                                    <a href="empleado.php?action=edit&id=<?php echo $empleado["id_empleado"]; ?>"
                                    type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Modificar</a>
                                    <a href="empleado.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $empleado["id_empleado"]; ?>"
                                    type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Se encontraron <?php echo count($data); ?> registros.</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
 } else {
   echo "No se encontraron registros. Ninguna tabla que mostrar.";
 }
 ?>
```